# Dictionary Type Shorthand Syntax error with XCode 7 / Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift2, xcode7

[image]

XCode 7 / Swift 2 spit out a bunch of errors on this code that is based on the snippet from the [Alamofire readme](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/swift-2.0/README.md#api-parameter-abstraction). I know nothing about Swift or iOS development, so any pointers would be appreciated here.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

enum PTVRouter: URLRequestConvertible {
    static let baseUrl = "http://timetableapi.ptv.vic.gov.au/"
    static let devId = "__CENSORED__"
    static let devKey = "__CENSORED__"

    case HealthCheck()

    var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
        let (path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?) = {
            switch self {
            case .HealthCheck():
                return ("/v2/healthcheck", ["devId": PTVRouter.devId])
            }
        }()

        let URL = NSURL(string: PTVRouter.baseUrl)!
        let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL

        return encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to reproduce your problem without downloading Alamofire, but try the following:

```
enum PTVRouter: URLRequestConvertible {
    static let baseUrl = "http://timetableapi.ptv.vic.gov.au/"
    static let devId = "__CENSORED__"
    static let devKey = "__CENSORED__"

    case HealthCheck

    var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
        let path: String
        let parameters: [String: AnyObject]

        switch self {
        case .HealthCheck:
            path = "/v2/healthcheck"
            parameters = ["devId": PTVRouter.devId]
        }
        let url = NSURL(string: PTVRouter.baseUrl)!
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL
        return encoding.encode(urlRequest, parameters: parameters).0
        return urlRequest
    }
}
```

Things to note:

The technique the example uses, where it creates a temporary closure and runs it immediately (what the `let (x,y) = { switch and return }()` is doing), is no longer necessary as of Swift 1.2 because deferred initialization of `let` variables is now possible. (they should really update that example code).

You don’t need to put `()` after the `case HealthCheck`.  The `()` are for including associated types with the case (in the example, they hold parameters for a query), and in your case, since you don’t have any, you don’t need the parens.

They declare the `parameters` variable as optional (presumably because the `parameters` argument of `encoding.encode` is optional). This isn’t necessary (non-optional arguments get upgraded to optional automatically) and it's generally a bad practice to declare things like arrays and dictionaries as optional – emptiness is usually sufficient, and the optionality can complicate things.

That said, your code looks like it ought to compile without these changes, but see if removing the clutter helps find whatever is actually wrong.

(and a couple of stylistic things, variables should start with lower case, even acronyms like “url”, to avoid them getting confused with types which start in upper case. also I wouldn’t use that force unwrap, rather I’d leave it optional, use optional chaining, and `fatalError` if it’s `nil` at the end but that’s just my personal preference)

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation. My issue appeared to be with the let syntax changing, when loading up a similar project in XCode and allowing it to auto-convert the Swift code, it changed the syntax to:
`let (path, parameters): (String, [String: AnyObject]?) = ...`

Is there any advantages of creating the temporary closure like they do rather than declaring the constants outside of the closure?

Comment: No, the temporary closure technique was a workaround before they introduced the ability to defer initialization of `let` variables.  Since that feature was added in Swift 1.2, the technique is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to specify the types of the tuple `(path, parameters)` in-place. You have to specify the types somewhere else:

In the beginning of the closure:

```
let (path, parameters) = {() -> (String, [String:AnyObject]?) in
    switch self {
    case .HealthCheck():
        return ("/v2/healthcheck", ["devId": PTVRouter.devId])
    }
}()
```

or as the tuple type after their names:

```
let (path, parameters) : (String, [String:AnyObject]?) = {
    switch self {
    case .HealthCheck():
        return ("/v2/healthcheck", ["devId": PTVRouter.devId])
    }
}()
```

Note that the syntax is really, really ugly in my opinion and obfuscates the actual working of the code in a big way.

Comment: it used to be the only way to initialize a `let` variable via a switch – without it, you had to use `var`. But this hasn’t been necessary since Swift 1.2 came out, the Alamofire readme should really be updated.